# Error: Could not cast or convert from System.String

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core

I get this error: `ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to API_STA_1.Classes.ProjectenEnPersoneelDATA.` when trying to convert data in json file to string.

[image]

The value i'm trying to get is `"unavailable"` and when I try to get a different value it does work, it only doesn't work with this value.

[image]

JSON:

[image]

Comment: What does the parent object containing `unavailable` look like in your json?

Comment: @weichch https://gyazo.com/6da836c78a4adb3b750554f6608e20e1

Comment: Ok what does the `ProjectsAndUsers` class look like? Does it have `unavailable` property?

Comment: Yes https://codeshare.io/5ORjQg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first I'd clarify the issue.

The OP had C# classes:

```
public class ProjectsAndUsers
{
    public IList<ProjectenEnPersoneelDATA> Unavailable { get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectenEnPersoneelDATA> Types { get; set; }
}


public class ProjectenEnPersoneelDATA
{
    public string[] unavailable { get; set;}

    public string title { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set;}
}
```

and JSON:

```
{
  "unavailable": [
    "2019-10-09",
    "2019-10-14",
    "2019-10-15",
    "2019-12-21",
    "2019-12-14",
    "2019-12-02",
    "2019-12-08"
  ],
  "types": [
    {
      "title": "Veiligheidsinspectie",
      "color": "#FF9D00"
    },
    {
      "title": "Kwaliteitscontrole",
      "color": "#B434DB"
    },
    {
      "title": "Bezet",
      "color": "#252525"
    }
  ]
}
```

**There is mismatch between C# types and JSON structure:**

`Unavailable` in JSON is an array of strings, whereas in C# class `ProjectsAndUsers` it is an array of objects of type `ProjectenEnPersoneelDATA`. This causes the exception.

To fix this, you need to adjust the C# types to:

```
public class ProjectsAndUsers
{
    public string[] unavailable { get; set;}
    public IList<ProjectenEnPersoneelDATA> Types { get; set; }
}


public class ProjectenEnPersoneelDATA
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the response you are getting from the WebClient. I Successfully parsed your JSON into your class. using the following.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var json = @"{""color"": ""red"", ""title"": ""Random Title"", 
        ""unavailable"": [""2010-10-09"", ""2010-10-19"", ""2010-10-20"",""2010-10- 
        29""]}";

        var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PDATA>(json);
        foreach (var item in res.unavailable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class PDATA
    {
        public string[] unavailable { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without referring to your serialized string. Add the following and check

```cs
var json = webclinet.DownloadString(path);
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json).ToString();
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourClass>(jsonResult);
```

Comment: still the same error https://gyazo.com/9d99ad9f08a14dfc14f6375b45f335c8

Comment: @T.v.A. can you post the downloaded string please?

Comment: sorry I don't understand, what do you want me to post?

Comment: the value you get into var json

Comment: There must be an issue in the json string you get from webClient.DownloadString() post that serialized value.

Comment: I tried a different string and that works fine, it's only the `unavailable` string that doesn't work